# Need to display PHP output to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Need to display PHP output to HTML page via  tag
heres's php :

```
<?php

mysql_connect("mysqldb3.ehost-services.com:3306","--username--","--password--") or die("No co to Db");
mysql_select_db("lasmif_count") or die("No Db");


$update_count = mysql_query("UPDATE user_count SET counts = counts+1");
$views = mysql_query("SELECT `user_count`.`counts` AS `views` FROM `user_count` ");
echo mysql_result($views,0);
 ?>
```

this php file is counting the number of visits

Now i want to insert the result of this in an html text tag

it is only displaying the number, nothing else.

Comment: Include some code of what you have tried so far so that somebody can help you.

Comment: You [shouldn't be using `mysql_` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: You might want to delete this and try again without your real username and password in the code

Comment: Your MySQL server is wide open to the internet. Change your password **IMMEDIATELY**.

Comment: `echo '<b>' . mysql_result($views,0) . '</b>';`

Comment: This is pretty much PHP 101. Have you taken a tutorial or read any book on PHP?

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick, you can either use php's `echo` function from the PHP part like this: `echo '<p>' . mysql_result($views,0) . '</p>';` or you could start a new html part below and do something like: `<p><?php echo mysql_results($views, 0); ?></p>`